# Find duplicate JARs in OSGi fat jar bundle

Tags: gradle, sbt, osgi, apache-felix, fatjar

I am currently working on a project that results in a fat JAR that runs in an OSGi context (Apache Felix). Is there a way/command to check if some of the jars that I have embedded into my fat jar are also available from other bundles and services, so that I can remove them (and thus make the fat jar smaller)?

The reason why I am building a fat jar is because I am using a different build system to build my jar. (I am using Scala & SBT, everything else is is built with Java & Gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any automated tools doing this, but Apache Felix has two tools that might help you find your duplicates:

1. `/system/console/depfinder`
2. `/system/console/status-duplicate_exports`

Especially, the second one should help you. It lists packages that are exported more than once and then it lists the bundles that export the those packages. If your bundle appears in this list, you know that another bundle exports packages, that are in your fat bundle.

But as with the `depfinder`, you will have to go through the list manually or write a little script to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: just have a look whether the JAR's you are currently including into your fat JAR are OSGi bundles (many IDE's tell that already in some project dependency view) and note down the header `Bundle-SymbolicName`.

Then you extract the same information from all bundles installed at the Felix runtime, e.g. using the [Gogo shell](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-gogo.html):

```
lb -s
```

...or if you have a directory with bundles for the runtime and the [`bnd`](https://bnd.bndtools.org/) command (and you're on a Unix):

```sh
find <bundles-directory> -type f -iname "*.[jw]ar" -exec bnd --failok print --manifest {} \; 2>/dev/null | grep -F 'Bundle-SymbolicName'
```

Now you can compare those lists against the SymbolicName's that you have found in your fat JAR. Once you found a match, you should also verify that the version is OK.